# Kernel flags for exact architecture

Tags: kernel, kernel-parameters

I am using linux-libre-4.17.3. I want to switch off all unnecescary stuff like 'Amateur radio', Xen, Hyper-V, Wifi drivers that I am not using and so on...

I think web search does not satisfy me. There are lot of questions that I cannot get. This is a very good stuff http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/Howto_configure_the_Linux_kernel

Please, give me more resources describing which kernel flags are using by my hardware (Lenovo G50-30) and tasks: wifi, dhcp, usb wireless mouse, snd_hda_intel, usb sticks.

Comment: Why not simply use as many loadable modules as possible? Solaris has everything inside loadable modules since 1992 and thus does not need a kernel config.

Comment: I want to optimize kernel boot time https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTRA1PRJWH8

Comment: Did you view this video? It does not mention kernel config as a method to speed up things but other more effective methods.

Answer (score 2):

Configuring a minimum kernel for fast boot times is not so easy, and one really needs to know what one wants/needs.

Very good source of knowledge in this area is the gentoo wiki, which has for many areas kernel config descriptions. Also the Arch Linux wiki contains many informations in that area. Further the kernel documentation is very helpful in many ways.

Basically what needs to be done starts at selecting the proper cpu/architecture options, network stacks to be used, hardware drivers for the devices, various graphic stack related settings, and hundreds/thousands other options.

It will take you many tries to find an optimum configuration, suiteable for all your requirements and hardware devices. The process is very interesting and one will learn a lot about the kernel, its main components, and the impressive amount of configuration options.

Expect that, if you aim for the fastest possible boot times, this process will take you days to months. Depending on the use case (and if binary firmware files are needed) it should be possible to build a kernel image of approx. 2 mb in size, having all needed components in it, without using initrd.

If you even want to speed it up further, have a look at the coreboot project. With the right hardware it should be possible to fit a previously optimized kernel into spi flash, booting directly without bootloader. Back in the days of rotating hard disks such a setup was faster than the spinup time of the hard drive, leading to situations where the boot would fail, as the disk was not ready to be read.